# typescript - map an array with sum

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function return an object like in the photo

```
this.events$ = this.disponibilityService.getDisponibilitiesByTeacher('a1')
.pipe(
   map((result: any) => {
     let teachers = result.map((item: any) => {
       return { startHour: item.startHour, endHour: item.endHour, year: item.startDate.split('-')[0] };
     });
     console.log(teachers);
  })
);
```

[image]

how can i map the result for return a array like below

nbr: number of years repeated

nbrHour: the sum of number of hours per year (number of hours = endHour - startHour)

```
[
  {nbr: 2, nbrHour: 630, year: 2020},
  {nbr: 1, nbrHour: 400, year: 2021}
]
```

Comment: Also why do you want year to be a string?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `number of years repeated`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode the year 2020 repeated twice, so nbr = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group data by year and then `map` the grouped, for each group, `nbr` will be the group size, `nbrHour` will be accumulated by the sum of `endHour - startHour` of all elements in that group

```js
const data = [
  { startHour: 800, endHour: 1200, year: "2020" },
  { startHour: 1400, endHour: 1800, year: "2021" },
  { startHour: 800, endHour: 1030, year: "2020" },
];

const groupByYear = Object.entries(
  data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (!acc[el.year]) {
      acc[el.year] = [el];
    } else {
      acc[el.year].push(el);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

const res = groupByYear.map(([year, data]) => ({
  nbr: data.length,
  nbrHour: data.reduce(
    (acc, { startHour, endHour }) => acc + endHour - startHour,
    0
  ),
  year,
}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

**References**

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): transform object to array of key-value pairs